# Wordpress query for users who have 2 equal meta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I get all users who have 2 custom meta field `meta_1` and `meta_2` of equal value?

For example:

```
// This user will be in the result
User 1:
meta_key : meta_1, meta_value: 6
meta_key : meta_2, meta_value: 6

// This user will also be in the result
User 2:
meta_key : meta_1, meta_value: 9001
meta_key : meta_2, meta_value: 9001

// This user will NOT be in the result
User 3:
meta_key : meta_1, meta_value: 25
meta_key : meta_2, meta_value: 6

// This user will NOT be in the result
User 4:
meta_key : meta_1, meta_value: 9001
// (this user does not have meta_2)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, user having meta_1 = 123 and meta_2 = 123 (anything other than _6_) should be in the result or not?

Comment: Yes they will be in the result, as long as the value of their meta_1 and meta_2 are equal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do this:

add an extra argument to *[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)*:

```
$args = array(
'equal_meta' => array('meta_1', 'meta_2')
);
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

and create [join filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters) for it:

```
function my_posts_join( $join, $query ) {

    if( _some_security_checks_if_needed ) {
       $rule = $query->get('equal_meta', array());
       if(!empty($rule) {
           ... write custom INNER JOIN using data from $rule
           $join .= $customJoin
       }
    }
    return $join;
}
```

I think that join is the best way, but there may be better... I'm not SQL guru ;)

And of course 'bind' that filter:

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'my_posts_join');
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
remove_filter('posts_join', 'my_posts_join');
```

If you want this filter to be applied to every *WP_Query* rather than specific one, then you should 'bind' it somewhere outside function, the best practice is to add it before/after function it calls:

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'my_posts_join');
function my_posts_join( $join, $query ) { ... }
```

Then you don't have to remove it.

**[ADDED SQL]**

Simpliest SQL query I could think of:

```
select wu.* from wp_users wu
-- two joins ensure we get only users with existing both meta values
inner join wp_usermeta wm1 on wm1.user_id = wu.ID and wm1.meta_key = 'meta_1'
inner join wp_usermeta wm2 on wm2.user_id = wu.ID and wm2.meta_key = 'meta_2'
-- now we filter only those with the same meta
where wm1.meta_value = wm2.meta_value;
```

This shows we will need two filters: posts_join, and posts_where. I hope you will manage to create both of them based on my answer.

$customJoin should look like this (pseudocode):

```
inner join wp_usermeta wm1 on wm1.user_id = wu.ID and wm1.meta_key = $rule[0]
inner join wp_usermeta wm2 on wm2.user_id = wu.ID and wm2.meta_key = $rule[1]
```

$customWhere:

```
AND wm1.meta_value = wm2.meta_value
```

Please note that in where there's AND, because $where (function's 1st argument) will actually include the beginning.

You should also add an empty space on the beginning of your custom query strings, otherwise they may produce invalid SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @m.cichacz . It would help a lot if you could guide me through the query & SQL process, since I know almost nothing about them. I have a db guy to help me with the query usually but he's not here today to ask ._.

Comment: I've added sample SQL. Try it and let me know if it works :)

Comment: Yes it work now! I had to change the exact query a bit here and there but it's working as I want, thanks a lot m.cichacz! :D

Comment: No problem :) Glad i could help you